# Question on Licenses

Tags: force.com, licenses

Is license tied to Salesforce/force.com App?

For example, we have an app and 50 users (with a mix of Salesforce and Platform licenses)  are using it, and we deploy another (force.com) app for the same users, do we need to purchase another license just for the additional app?

Or we can (legally) utilize the existing license, and we just need to pay for additional app and its custom objects?

Additionally, if we have 2 Salesforce Communities, which will be accessed by Partner users, can these communities be accessed as well by the aforementioned 50 users?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Licenses are based on users. If you add additional user then you need Licenses. Creating app does not require Licenses.

Comment: if we have 2 Salesforce Communities, which will be accessed by Partner users, can these communities be accessed as well by the aforementioned 50 users?

Comment: Yes !! User Licenses and Community Licenses are different.  But user can access communities also without any cost. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/02/salesforce-communities-licenses.html